# How is the position of an electron made?

Tags: electrons, measurements, quantum-measurements

The position of an electron is often discussed in physics. My question is simple. How does one go about measuring an electron’s position ? It seems like an impossible task.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146023/what-is-the-experiment-used-to-actually-observe-the-position-of-the-electron-in

Comment: It would be great to hear a concrete example of how it is actually done.

Comment: Anna's answer in the link shows it for an electron in a H-atom, scattering light off of the atom. Other than bound states, I don't think it's possible to measure the position of a free *electron* in, say, a current.

Comment: @RenanNobuyukiHirayama thanks for your interest in my question. Scattering light off an atom seems impossible too. The light wave is larger than the atom. I don’t doubt that it is done. I would like a few more details if possible.

Comment: Have a look at these
1) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900205006169
2) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900201017636
3) https://news.mit.edu/2015/magnetic-system-detects-single-electrons-0421
4) https://www.osti.gov/pages/biblio/1332971

Comment: None of these measurements measure the electron’s position. They show the electrons path or evidence of its existence. Often the discussions in physics speak of a election’s location suggesting that it has a place that can be named.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the position of the electron, we must interact with it, such as having it collide with a detector. The answer to this question gives a little more background
[What is the experiment used to actually observe the position of the electron in the H atom?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146023/what-is-the-experiment-used-to-actually-observe-the-position-of-the-electron-in)

Comment: How is its position named? Is a location assigned like coordinates? A position has references points.

Comment: Yes it will have coordinates in three dimensional space