# How do we measure an electron's position by shining light on it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, quantum-measurements

I saw [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/653080/366605) which says:

> The way you do it is just a simple logic. Imagine a tennis ball and imagine you can't really see it, just like you can't see an electron. So the only way you can see where the tennis ball is is to hit it with another tennis ball or with an enormous amount of light that it will actually displace the tennis ball position, move it that is. At that moment the light brings you the information into your eyes and you see the tennis ball.

Does the author mean the reflected light? Because if the light isn't reflected (i.e. a new photon emitted), how would we see the electron or tennis ball? It seems like, unless light is reflected/a new photon is emitted, we won't be able to see the electron.

If my reasoning is correct, then we can't detect electrons in the photoelectric effect this way, because no photons are emitted in that case, but we can in the Compton effect. Is my reasoning correct or did I make a mistake?

Comment: Photons don't come with identity tags, so whether an outgoing photon from an interaction is the same as the incoming photon is entirely a matter of your choice in how to think about it.

Comment: true, but if the photon isn't reflected, how will we see the electron in that case ?

Comment: You might consider the photon to have been absorbed, and a different photon to have been emitted.

Comment: So this is what happens in compton/thompson then, right ? not that it's reflected, but absorbed and then, emitted a new one ?

Comment: Either one. A photon comes in, a photon goes out. Whether it's reflected or absorbed/emitted is a distinction that exists in your mind, but not in reality. There's no experiment that can distinguish.

Comment: But it turns out detecting the electron position with this way is not correct as @naturallyInconsistent points out. I wonder exactly what's wrong with it. since new photon is emitted from the interaction, we look at it and see the new photon, hence we detected the position at that point. I understand that after `x` sec, the position won't be the same, but still, at that very exact moment, we saw the new photon. What's wrong with this ?

Comment: Related: [How does measuring electron position happen?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/765371/how-does-measuring-electron-position-happen)

Comment: To "see" means you have a lens and a screen ... like in your eye or with a camera .... to have an image.  Many electrons pass thru the slit and many deflect photons but only a few electrons deflect a photon to the detector ..... it is NOT seeing .... we just know (assume) that because the slit is small and the light/camera was aimed at the slit that the electron was briefly there!  Of course "interference" is destroyed.

Comment: Electrons are quanta of energy. They don't have a position. The only "position" we are ever measuring is the position of the matter that emits or absorbs this amount of energy.

Answer (score 1):

That is a rather standard misunderstanding of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle. Experimentalists tend to like to argue this way because it easily relates with one of the facts of doing experiments: when you want to measure something, there must be some disturbance. And Heisenberg himself also made this mistake.

But HUP is really a mathematical theorem. It is a mathematical relation between a basis and its Fourier transform. The experimental uncertainties necessarily have to be bigger than HUP limits, but are otherwise independent from HUP.

And no, you do not get to insist on an easy answer and avoid talking about wavefunctions and probabilities. We have reality, and if you want to learn about reality, you have to consider reality as Nature wants to talk about.

Comment: I try to avoid wavefunctions as I don't understand them yet. That's the only reason. So what I described doesn't really happen ? then, the link I pasted and quote from it should be wrong no ?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong, because it is repeating the age old arguments about HUP coming from experiments. Instead, the accepted answer is much better. The reality is just so complicated.

Comment: but what exactly is wrong ? with compton/thompson, we know that light is absorbed and re-emitted and since a new one is re-emitted, we can see the electron.

Comment: From which part? With only one photon you cannot really figure out anything.

Comment: In compton, you shine a light on electron and new photon is emitted. with looking at this NEW photon, we can detect the electron position. What's wrong with this ? this is what the author from my link says.

Comment: If the photon is of visible light, then the wavelength of the photon alone is about thousands of atoms, making a volume of much bigger than that. You have to go to X rays before you can get to something on the order of the size of one electron orbital, and then you have to know that there is no such thing as an X ray lens, you cannot tell that the X ray that came out, came from where. You cannot make little pixelated pictures of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146260/discussion-between-nika-and-naturallyinconsistent).

Comment: @Nika, if you want to actually understand anything in QM, there's no getting around wavefunctions.  So instead of avoiding them because you don't understand them yet, I suggest you do some reading about them.

Answer (score 1):

A long comment from an experimentalist.

The electron is a quantum mechanical entity, its interactions have to be modeled and discussed with this in mind. At the level of the electron there are no reflections, because reflections of light involve many quantum particles of light, and there can be only one photon scattering off another quantum entity, whether a molecule, an atom or an electron.

If the scattering is with an atom, a photon may be absorbed with an electron kicked off, if there is enough energy in the photon. *May* means there is a probability, which can be calculated using the theory of quantum mechanics. There *may* be an exiting photon if there is enough energy( there will be a distinct [spectral line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line) photon when the atom settles down to its original state).

The Feynman diagrams used to pictorially order the mathematical formulas for calculating all this help in giving an iconic representation. For simple "electron photon" scattering where the electron is free one has

[image: compton]

These two diagrams are necessary in order to calculate how probable the scattering is and to be able to check the prediction with data from the accumulation of many such scatterings. This needs studying a course on quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Light is often used in experiments to make observations of particle that cannot be detected otherwise. This is standard practice in trapped ion experiments for example. The basic idea is to observe the changes in the light. There are various ingenious ways to make such observation. So it may be observations of light from Compton scattering, or it could be missing light due to absorption. Note that the scattering or absorption may destroy the state that being observed. But that does not matter, because the experimenter just wants to know what the state is just before the scattering/absorption took place. Sometimes the experimenter wants to make several observations to see the evolution of the state. In those cases the experiment would be repeated and the illumination with the light would be delayed progressively to obtain information at different time delays to build up the information about the evolution.